# Login page is not showing upon startup as intended

Tags: android

I am very new to Android app development and Android Studio, so please be kind here! I have encountered an error after following several tutorials and I cannot seem to find any errors/errors being shown on the platform.

First, a brief background explanation. I have 3 different pages currently, which are the login page, a forget password page and a dashboard (empty) page.

The problem here is that the dashboard page is showing up upon start up even though I have programmed the login page to be shown first. I have redone the entire code and process twice. On the second time, it does actually work as intended but when I woke up this morning to test the code again it did not work again (did not touch any part of the code from when it did work and until today morning).

I am hoping that someone could help me solve my issue as I took quite some time doing this. Another thing to take note of is that I have connected it to Firebase. The classes and xml files of all 3 pages look fine to me so I am unsure as to why I have this problem.

I will post my manifest file, my 3 classes and my gradle files. If I need to post anymore do tell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.samuel.a1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/LoginActivityTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Dashboard" />
        <activity android:name=".ForgetPassword"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Login Page

```
package com.example.samuel.a1;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView inputEmail;
private EditText Name;
private EditText Password;
private Button Login;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    inputEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvForgotPassword);

    inputEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForgetPassword.class));
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class));
    }
    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validate(Name.getText().toString(), Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void validate(String userName, String userPassword) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, userPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

ForgetPassword

```
package com.example.samuel.a1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class ForgetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail;
private Button sendEmail;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forget_password);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etinputemail);
    sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnsend);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String useremail = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (useremail.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please enter your corporate email ID.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(useremail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "The email to reset your password has been sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Unable to send email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Dashboard

```
package com.example.samuel.a1; 

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
}
}
```

Gradle, module:app

```
buildscript {

        repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
        dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these line are wrong.

<strike>*Maybe because you not logout from application? I found the same problem when I use FirebaseAuthentication. If you not log out, when you use your application again it will think that you enter with same account.*</strike>

*P.S. Sorry, my English skill is quite bad.*

---

Edit, It's my bad. What I mention above are wrong. Because I not use FirebaseAuth for a long time. I think I find your problem.

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class));
}
```

These line cause your problem because when LoginActivity start it will check your lastest user, and if you not log out it will use the lastest login account as your FirebaseUser. And it will never be null except for the first login because you never log out from this application.

Comment: Ok! I'll give it a try and let you know! Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Hi, I've been thinking about what you said; While it seems like this is the root of the problem, when I press the back button on the emulator, it backs me out of the entire application where else previously if it were to work as intended, it should have backed me into the login page. I wonder if just by solving the issue you pointed out will change this problem too, thanks!

Comment: With you code, you cannot back to LogInActivity from Dashboard because your LoginActivity already closed because you declare finish() when you start new activity.

Comment: You can override onDestroy() in LoginActivity then use some Log in there. You will see that your LoginActivity destroyed.

Comment: And I know now why you mention that you can back to LoginActivity. In your validate() method you not declare final that why you can back to LoginActivity. But the problem is that if you already login validate() method will not called.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for your explanation! I'll try it out soon! Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry I was sick yesterday. I tried it out today and I got it working again! Thank you very much, I have accepted yours as the answer. Thank you!